# Using LINQ to search two lists for match and return boolean for every item

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to check two lists say for example looks like this

```
list1 = {"br","je"}; 
list2 = {"banana", "bread", "jam", "brisket", "flakes", "jelly"};
```

should return

```
{false, true, false, true, false, true}
```

Using LINQ is it possible to achieve the above output. I tried something below like this

```
    public static IEnumerable<bool> ContainsValues(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
    List<bool> res = new List<bool>();

    foreach (string item in list1)
    {
        foreach (string sub in list2)
        {
            res.Add(item.ToLower().Contains(sub.ToLower()));
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: You could maybe use a left join to do this.  I don't think that'd be a better approach, but it would use LINQ.

Comment: Your example code, the stuff you want us to re-write in LINQ, does not match your example output. Your output contains only six elements but the code would generate 12, since it will take a cross product. What is the actual output that you want?

Comment: I want the output to be the same count of items as the **list2** since i am checking the **list1** against it.

Comment: @Watarap your current code will not generate the expected output. As you are using nested for loop, the output list will contain *list1Count x list2Count* number of elements.

Comment: @Faruq - Sorry I now realised that I was cross lacing by having nested loops. The output is the one I desire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can re-write your existing code in a single statement:

```
public static IEnumerable<bool> ContainsValues(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
    return
        from item in list1
        from sub in list2
        select item.ToLower().Contains(sub.ToLower());
}
```

However, your existing code does not provide the sample results you want. To get the results you're looking for, I think you want something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<bool> SecondContainsFirst(List<string> first, 
    List<string> second)
{
    return second.Select(s => first.Any(f => 
        s.IndexOf(f, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) > -1);
}
```

Here's sample usage:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var list1 = new List<string> {"br", "je"};
    var list2 = new List<string> {"banana", "bread", "jam", "brisket", "flakes", "jelly"};
    var result = SecondContainsFirst(list1, list2);

    Console.WriteLine($"{{{string.Join(", ", result)}}}");

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You need to "flip" the lists, such that you are looking for the full words (list2) contain the letter sequences (list1) to achieve OP's desired output.

Comment: Sorry, but it simply does not do what was required.

Comment: @koryakinp I updated the answer since the question is really two different things - 1. Can the method code be converted to Linq, and 2. Can it produce the specified results. So now I've given both... :)

Comment: Surely `f => s.IndexOf(f, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0` (or add cultures info etc.) is better than `f => s.ToLower().Contains(f.ToLower())` - 2 x ToLower() (2 x ToUpper()s is better than that considering how .Net handles strings too)

Comment: @Martino Yes, definitely. I was just using the OPs original code there, but have updated to use `IndexOf`. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<bool> res = list2.Select(q => list1.Any(q.Contains));
```

Comment: I would recommend this answer, with the caveat I would use "string.Equals(w, q, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)" instead of the == comparer on strings.  (or whichever comparer is best for you use case)

Comment: I would use `q => item.IndexOf(q, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`

Answer (score 2):

Later and identical to then [koryakinp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49018745/7505395) - took me time to make it a full fledged example - which his is not.

`list2.Select(item => list1.Any(l1 => item.IndexOf(l1,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));` will produce the desired output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new List<string> { "br", "je" };
        var list2 = new List<string> { "banana", "bread", "jam", 
                                       "brisket", "flakes", "jelly" };

        var res = list2.Select(item => 
            list1.Any(l1 => item.IndexOf(l1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));


        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list1));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list2));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", res));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
br,je
banana, bread, jam, brisket, flakes, jelly
False,True,False,True,False,True  // no idea why yours are lower case
```

---

Suggested edit:

- thanks @Martino - [String.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?#Remarks) suggest:

> To determine whether a string contains a specified substring by using something other than ordinal comparison (such as culture-sensitive comparison, or ordinal case-insensitive comparison), you can create a custom method. The following example illustrates one such approach.

Followed by an example using `IndexOf()` + desired `StringComparison`.

Comment: Same as koryakinp -  and later as well, took me more time to make it a full example which his is not.

Comment: I would give it +1 if you corrected `item.ToLower().Contains(l1.ToLower())` to `item.IndexOf(l1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`

Comment: @Martino good suggestions, correlates with [String.Contains - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?#Remarks) as well

Answer (score 1):

If only because all 3 current answers used, IMHO, troublesome string operations:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list1 = new List<string> { "br", "je" };
    var list2 = new List<string> { "banana", "bread", "jam", "brisket", "flakes", "jelly" };

    var result = string.Join(",",ContainsValues(list1, list2));

    Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(",",list1)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(",", list2)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
    Console.Read();

    IEnumerable<bool> ContainsValues(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2) =>
      lst2.Select(l2 => lst1.Any(l1 => l2.IndexOf(l1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
}   

`
```

`